Performance Issues with MERGE Procedure in Oracle - Wrong query?
I am currently facing performance issues with an Oracle stored procedure that performs a MERGE operation between two tables. The purpose of this procedure is to archive changes from one table to another, but it is taking too much time it never ends.
I have two tables: the first table gets overwritten periodically, and I want to create a new table that detects changes and archives them.
SOURCE: My source table is a view, This view is build like this:
Select
      t.field1,
      t.key1,
      t.date,
      t.type,
      t.component
From table A

Union ALL

Select
   some complex manipulation   as t.field1
   t.key1,
   t.date,
   t.type,
   t.component
from table b

DESTINATION: my destination is a table with the same structure as the view. In this table we should write a new row everytime an update or insert is made on the view.
How should I do this?
Any help would be much apreciated.
thanks
I've tried this but it takes too long,
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ArchiveData AS
BEGIN
  MERGE INTO target_table t
  USING source_table s ON (t.key1 = s.key1 AND t.date = s.date AND t.type = s.type AND t.component = s.component)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (
      t.field1,
      t.key1,
      t.date,
      t.type,
      t.component,
   
    ) VALUES (
      s.field1,
      s.key1,
      s.date,
      s.type,
      s.component,
   
    );
END ArchiveData;

I waited like 2 hours and it's still running, even if the tables involved are just 5k rows.
If I try to build the view without the UNION ALL, so getting the data just from tableA or just from tableB it works perfectly fine, and it runs in 0.2 seconds. But if I build the view using the UNION ALL when i run the procedure it never ends

You haven't shown any table or index DDL or execution plan information to assist with performance; but if it's taking that long are you sure you don't just have uncommitted changes to the target table in another session, which are blocking this from doing anything?

Sorry, I'm not very experienced with this. I wrote the query, but what do you mean by "show the tables"? My question is, should I solve my problem in a different way? It's possible that I constructed the query incorrectly. Should I consider another approach?


I am currently facing performance issues with an Oracle stored procedure that performs a MERGE operation between two tables. The purpose of this procedure is to archive changes from one table to another, but it is taking a significantly long time to complete.

The tables that you are trying to modify may have been modified by another session but that session has not issued a COMMIT or ROLLBACK so the table/row is locked and the other session is waiting for the lock to be released.
Try running the procedure and if the code is waiting "forever" then go to whatever other clients you are using (i.e. SQL Developer, SQL*Plus, etc. or whichever tool you have that has an open session with uncommitted data) and run a COMMIT (or ROLLBACK) command and see if the procedure then suddenly completes. If it does then it was waiting for the lock to be released on the table/row.
If you don't know which session has locked the row then you can try closing everything else and, when the connection is closed, it will implicitly ROLLBACK any changes. If there are multiple users using the table then ask all of them to COMMIT their sessions. If this still doesn't work then you can try terminating all the inactive sessions connected to the database (ask your colleagues first just so you don't kill something that someone is actively using).

Thank you for the suggestion, but the problem isn't that. There's no conflict between sessions or processes, or in any case, the issue isn't that the procedure is queuing up.
What I've come to understand is that the problem stems from the view. My source is a view, and as long as the view is pulling from a single table, everything works perfectly and quickly. However, if I modify the view by adding a UNION ALL with another table, at that point the procedure stops working.

@Gabry You need to edit your question and include a [MRE] with the complete details of your tables, views and queries. If you only give us half the information then we cannot answer for your specific problem because you haven't told us about the specific problem. Nowhere in the question do you mention views or using UNION ALL.

Thank you for the help and sorry for the confusion. I'm not very experienced with this, so I'm not sure how to properly ask the question. I have edited my post; is it okay now? Have I provided enough information? Please let me know. Thanks!
